# How to display the div element one by one for parallax landing element using CSS3 effects?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, css-transitions

I am trying to make a `parallax` landing element using JS and CSS effects, i.e. when scrolling the page the content of the div(images) should display sequentially one by one.

In my code, I am able to display the content of the div in `CSS3` effects(transition and translate) using JS, but **I want it to display sequentially.**

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
     
      var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
     
     $('.logo').css({
      'transform':'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /2 +'%)'
      });
      
     $('.back-bird').css({
      'transform':'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /8 +'%)'
      });
     
     $('.fore-bird').css({
      'transform':'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /95 +'%)'
      });
      
      
     if(wScroll > $('.clothes').offset().top-($(window).height()/0.25)){
         
      $('.clothes').each(function(i){
       
       setTimeout(function(){
        $('.clothes').eq(i).addClass('is-showing');
       }, 150*(i+1));
      });
     
      
     }
       
     });
```

```css
    body{
     width:auto;
     height:auto;
    }
    
    .content{
     width:90%;
     height:3500px;
     background:#BCE8E2; 
     margin:auto;
    }
    
    .birdbox{
     width:inherit;
     height: 600px;
     background:url(MOUN.jpg) no-repeat top center;
     background-size:cover;
     margin: 20px 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
     }
    
    .content1{
    width:inherit;
    height:1200px;
    background:#F9F9F9;
     margin: 20px 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .logo{
     height:120px;
     width:100%;
     background:url(logo.png) no-repeat center;
     position:absolute;
     top:30%;
     margin-top:-50px; 
     }
    
    .fore-bird{
         width: 90%;
        height: 898px;
        background: url(EGALE2.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 500px;
        /* opacity: 0.6; */
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        background-position: 468px 80px;
     position:absolute;
     top: 126px;
     
    }
    .back-bird{
     width: 90%;
     height:390px;
     background:url(shadowbrid.png) no-repeat;
     background-size:180px; 
     position: absolute;
        left: 10%;
        top: 5%;
    }
    
    h1,p{
     text-align:center; 
    }
    
    
    .clothes{
     width: 95%;
        margin: 10px 269px;
     position:relative;
     opacity:0;
     transform:translateX(20px);
     transition: all 3s linear 0.5s;
     }
     
     .is-showing{
     opacity:1; 
     transfrom: translateX(0px); 
     }
     
    .row1{
        width: inherit;
        float: left;
    }
     
    .large{
     margin: 100px auto;
        height: 400px;
        width: 28%;
        background: url(model1.jpg) top center no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        border-radius: 67%;
    }
```

```html
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
        <title>Fixed background Moving element</title>
        </head>
         <body>
        <div class="content">
        <header class="birdbox">
        <div class="back-bird"></div>
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="fore-bird"></div>
        </header>
        <section class="content1">
        <h1>Spread Love Studio</h1>
        
        <hr>
        
        <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
        <hr>
        <div class="clothes">
         <div class="row1">
            <img src="model1.jpg" style="width:200px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" alt="Model"/> 
            <img src="model2.jpg" style="width:200px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" alt="Model"/>
            <img src="model3.jpg" style="width:200px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" alt="Model"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
           <img src="model1.jpg" style="width:200px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" alt="Model"/> 
            <img src="model2.jpg" style="width:200px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" alt="Model"/>
            <img src="model3.jpg" style="width:200px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" alt="Model"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
            <img src="model1.jpg" style="width:200px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" alt="Model"/> 
            <img src="model2.jpg" style="width:200px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" alt="Model"/>
            <img src="model3.jpg" style="width:200px; margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;" alt="Model"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        </section>
        <div class="large">
        </div>
        
        
        </div>
        
        
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../para.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Stupid question maybe ..... are you sure jQuery is loaded? I'm asking since you are using the '$' and other jQuery syntax. and in your HTML i cant find the link

Comment: Yes, it is JQuery and I have linked the script at the bottom of the HTML code(para.js).